# Why boundary molecules have more energy?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, energy

In a system of a solid or a liquid, why do the molecules at the interface have more energy, compared to the bulk of solid or liquid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surface effects!  The molecules, atoms, nucleons, etc at the edge of a bulk material are exposed to a different environment than those in the interior.  Since the bulk material is bound, the interior constituents have a higher binding energy than those at the edge.  This makes those constituents near the edge more weakly bound which is equivalent to having a higher energy.

Comment: "which is equivalent to having a higher energy"

Why do you say that?  molecules inside the bulk have more potential energy and at the edge molecules have more kinetic energy

Comment: @Mohi the binding energy is negative...potential energy has a greater negative value in the bulk...so outer molecules have a higher energy...

Comment: Or, put differently, exterior atoms have unsatisfied or highly strained bonds.

Comment: Thanks guys for answering @Mohi question before I got back to it.

Comment: Can we say that, less binding energy means less stability. Consequently, they have more energy. Isn't?

Comment: @Kaushik yes, that sounds right.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are asking this question with in relation to surface tension at interfaces. Molecules at interfaces don't have 'more' or 'less' energy by definition it's just that the net interaction force on molecules in the bulk is zero because the molecule is surrounded by molecules of the same type everywhere around it. Contrary to the bulk, at the interface, a molecule is on one side surrounded by molecules of the same type and on the other side of another type. Therefore the net interaction force is no longer zero and there exist a surface tension force because the molecule at the interface is being pulled into one phase more than another.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I got my answer by Lewis Miller

Comment: but I voted your answer because I learned from it